# I bought a house with my mother she is not paying her half of the mortgage

Tags: mortgage

I bought a house with my mother and both of our names are on the mortgage and she is not now paying her portion and we are almost a month behind. What can I do?

Comment: Do you both live in the house? Do either of you wish to continue living there? Is your mother likely to be able to catch-up on her portion? Are you able and willing to cover for her for some period of time?

Answer (score 3):

Between your mother and you the bank does not care where the payments come from. If they do not get them, they can sue you, or your mother or (most likely) both of you and they will chase whichever of you has the most money and ultimately repossess the house to satisfy the debt.

What matters between you is the contract or deed that you signed with your mother where you documented that you would each pay half of the mortgage.

Unfortunately, agreements between family members are presumed **not** to be contracts. That is, the courts will not get involved to decide how much each of you owe - you have to sort that out for yourselves.

A signed agreement will usually overcome that presumption. Other evidence may overcome the presumption - for example, evidence that you split the payments 50/50 for some period of time.

Talk to your mother. And a lawyer.